# How do I get the image and text on the same line?

Tags: html, css, alignment, positioning

I'm doing a counselling website for my mom, and I've got a contact details section and I'm trying to get the text and the image on the same line, but I don't know how to do it, I've tried putting the image and the text in a paragraph tag, but it hasn't worked, I've also tried lowering the font size of the text and that didn't work, bear in mind I'm doing the mobile size first, 320px.

This is what it's meant to look like:
[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="evettedetails">
    <h2>Evette</h2>
        <p><img src="images/social_icons/phone-4-16.jpg" class="mobile">Phone number</p>
        <p><img src="images/social_icons/email-16.jpg" class="mobile">Email Address</p>
        <p><img src="images/social_icons/linkedin-3-16.jpg" class="mobile">Linked In</p>
</div>

<div id="shieladetails">
    <h2>Shiela</h2>
        <img src="images/social_icons/phone-4-16.jpg" class="mobile"><p>Phone number</p>
        <img src="images/social_icons/email-16.jpg" class="mobile"><p>Email Address</p>
        <img src="images/social_icons/linkedin-3-16.jpg" class="mobile"><p>Linked In</p>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#contact_details h2 {
    font-family: 'museo300', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #0679B2;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#contact_details h3 {
    font-family: 'museo300', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #0679B2;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#contact_details p {
    font-family: 'museo300', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #0679B2;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#contact_details #evettedetails {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#contact_details #shieladetails {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example that shows the issue? Your example CSS references an element with the ID of `contact_details` that doesn't exist in your HTML sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block` on the ids "evettedetails" and "sheiladetails" and also on the image tags. Also close the `img` tags properly. That should solve your problem.

[Here is the jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3a81v304/2/)

Code Snippet follows...

```css
#contact_details h2 {
  font-family: 'museo300', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #0679B2;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#contact_details h3 {
  font-family: 'museo300', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #0679B2;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#contact_details p {
  font-family: 'museo300', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #0679B2;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#evettedetails,
#shieladetails {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="evettedetails">
  <h2>Evette</h2>

  <div>
    <img src="images/social_icons/phone-4-16.jpg" class="mobile" />
    <p>Phone number</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/social_icons/email-16.jpg" class="mobile" />
    <p>Email Address</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/social_icons/linkedin-3-16.jpg" class="mobile" />
    <p>Linked In</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="shieladetails">
  <h2>Shiela</h2>

  <div>
    <img src="images/social_icons/phone-4-16.jpg" class="mobile" />
    <p>Phone number</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/social_icons/email-16.jpg" class="mobile" />
    <p>Email Address</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="images/social_icons/linkedin-3-16.jpg" class="mobile" />
    <p>Linked In</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps